# How to insert/merge multiple extracted subsets into a dataset based the same names in rows

Tags: r

I want to extract the rows with end.time is not NA, and combine this subset to the original dataset. With only one ID, it's pretty easy I know how to do it, as my makeup example and code below,

```
  Data <-         ID         start.time  end.time   EVENT 
             1   aaa           NA         21:00     1
             2   aaa           NA         17:00     1
             3   aaa          13:00        NA       2


 Subs1<-subset(Data, (!is.na(Data[,3])) )
 bind1=rbind(Data,Subs1)
```

However, if there're multiple IDs... I cannot simply use rbind to bind them together, I have looked into the insert function, but I want to insert the subset directly following the same ID

For example,

```
Data2  <-         ID         start.time  end.time   EVENT 
             1   aaa           NA         21:00     1
             2   aaa           NA         17:00     1
             3   aaa          13:00        NA       2
             4   bbb          12:00       15:00     2
             5   bbb           NA         23:00     3
             6   ccc          09:00        NA       4
```

My desired result should be as below,

```
NewData2  <-         ID         start.time  end.time   EVENT 
                 1   aaa           NA         21:00     1
                 2   aaa           NA         17:00     1
                 3   aaa          13:00        NA       2
                 4   aaa           NA         21:00     1
                 5   aaa           NA         17:00     1
                 6   bbb          12:00       15:00     2
                 7   bbb           NA         23:00     3
                 6   bbb          12:00       15:00     2
                 7   bbb           NA         23:00     3
                 8   ccc          09:00        NA       4
```

I've looked around and cannot really find a way to do it...
I would appreciate any suggestions and help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base R we can first `subset` `Data2` and `rbind` it to original dataframe and then use `order` to arrange it by `ID`

```
df <- rbind(Data2, subset(Data2, !is.na(end.time)))
df[order(df$ID), ]

#    ID start.time end.time EVENT
#1  aaa       <NA>    21:00     1
#2  aaa       <NA>    17:00     1
#3  aaa      13:00     <NA>     2
#11 aaa       <NA>    21:00     1
#21 aaa       <NA>    17:00     1
#4  bbb      12:00    15:00     2
#5  bbb       <NA>    23:00     3
#41 bbb      12:00    15:00     2
#51 bbb       <NA>    23:00     3
#6  ccc      09:00     <NA>     4
```

---

With `dplyr` you could `filter` the non-NA `end.time` and use `bind_rows` to add them into the original dataframe and then `arrange` by `ID`

```
library(dplyr)

Data2 %>%
  filter(!is.na(end.time)) %>%
  bind_rows(Data2) %>%
  arrange(ID)

#    ID start.time end.time EVENT
#1  aaa       <NA>    21:00     1
#2  aaa       <NA>    17:00     1
#3  aaa       <NA>    21:00     1
#4  aaa       <NA>    17:00     1
#5  aaa      13:00     <NA>     2
#6  bbb      12:00    15:00     2
#7  bbb       <NA>    23:00     3
#8  bbb      12:00    15:00     2
#9  bbb       <NA>    23:00     3
#10 ccc      09:00     <NA>     4
```